# PC will be turned off in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, dell-inspiron, safe-mode

I wanted to scan a Dell inspiron N5010 laptop in safe mode. When I took it to the safe mode environment and ran the AV to scan, after some while the PC went out!
The *power options* menu options (when plug is in) are as follows:

*Screensaver* after 4 mins.
*Dim to display* after 10 mins.
*Turn off display* after 15 mins.
*Hard disk*, *sleep* and *hibernate* are all off (set to never).

I tested the machine without scanning it, i.e, went to the safe mode and waited to see what occurs after time elapsing.

By observations so far (because I can apply more tests to determine that where the problem exactly is), the problem is when the machine is in safe mode and is doing something (in current case, scanning).
What do you think? Why it goes out in this situation please?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the [event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) for further details?

Comment: The computer is turning off or shutdowning or restarting?

Comment: Shutting down probably.

Comment: In safe mode I disabled Dim to display and also turn off display (the screen saver can't be changed because it's not accessible in safe mode). What occurs is this, machine goes off, that is, it'll be turned off after few minutes without any sound/message or something like this. 

Now I've come out from safe mode and in normal mode and normal Power Options (10 min dim to display and 15 min for turning off the display) I'm scanning the PC. 
I post the result again as soon as possible.

Comment: In normal mode, after passing about 24 mins it turned off! Without even any sound of message. The laptop has the problem of heating, that is, it heats and sends out the very heating air from it's vents always. I don't know the problem is that heat or some thing else.